# How to check if a variable has been assigned a value in AutoHotkey?

Tags: operators, undefined, autohotkey, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

```
#Warn

WinActivate ahk_class %PrevActiveClass%
```

When running the above code, the interpreter throws:

[image]

I want to check if `PrevActiveClass` has been assigned a value, if it has, then run `WinActivate`, how to implement this logic in AutoHotkey?

Comment: You are getting this warning message because you have #Warn set in your code. It's warning you that the variable PrevActiveClass is being used before being assigned a value. To avoid this you can assign an empty value to that var in the auto-execute section: `PrevActiveClass := ""`

Comment: @user3419297 Thanks, is it safe to remove `#Warn`? I found the warning in this case is rather unnecessary since the code is cleaner and runs fine. Do you enable `#Warn` for your scripts?

Comment: [#Warn](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Warn.htm) can be useful because it can indicate an error, such as a typo or a missing "global" declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [#Warn](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Warn.htm):

> Enables or disables warnings for specific conditions which may indicate an error, such as a typo or missing "global" declaration.
>
> ```
> #Warn [WarningType, WarningMode]
> ```
>
> `WarningType`
>
> > The type of warning to enable or disable. If omitted, it defaults to `All`.
> >
> > `UseUnsetLocal` or `UseUnsetGlobal`: Warn when a variable is read without having previously been assigned a value or initialized with [`VarSetCapacity()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/VarSetCapacity.htm). If the variable is intended to be empty, assign an empty string to suppress this warning.
> >
> > **This is split into separate warning types for locals and globals because it is more common to use a global variable without prior initialization, due to their persistent and script-wide nature. For this reason, some script authors may wish to enable this type of warning for locals but disable it for globals.** [emphasis added]
> >
> > ```
> > #Warn
> > ; y := "" ; This would suppress the warning.
> > x := y ; y hasn't been assigned a value.
> > ```

In this case, it's safe to turn off the warning for `UseUnsetGlobal`:

```
#Warn
#Warn UseUnsetGlobal, Off

WinActivate ahk_class %PrevActiveClass%
```

Comment: It's nice that you add your own answers as well, but I must say that while this is probably what you were looking for, it is not the answer to the question you asked. Your answer is an answer to how to disable a specific warning. And your question was how to check if a variable has been assigned a value.

Comment: @0x464e Your suggestion makes sense, but since this answer really resolves my issue, I think that's what "accept" is for, if others found this answer doesn't suit their needs, they can look for other answers on this page.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to check whether or not a variable has been set, you can do that by comparing its address<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#unary)</sup> to the address of a non-existent variable:

```
var1 := ""      ;will return non-existent, this doesn't actually really create a variable
var2 := "hello" ;will return non-empty
var3 := "test"  ;now a variable actually gets created
var3 := ""      ;but here we set it to be empty, so it'll return empty
var4 := false   ;will return non-empty
;var5           ;will return non-existent


MsgBox, % (&Var1 = &NonExistentVar ? "Non-existent" : (Var1 = "" ? "Empty" : "Non-empty")) "`n"
        . (&Var2 = &NonExistentVar ? "Non-existent" : (Var2 = "" ? "Empty" : "Non-empty")) "`n"
        . (&Var3 = &NonExistentVar ? "Non-existent" : (Var3 = "" ? "Empty" : "Non-empty")) "`n"
        . (&Var4 = &NonExistentVar ? "Non-existent" : (Var4 = "" ? "Empty" : "Non-empty")) "`n"
        . (&Var5 = &NonExistentVar ? "Non-existent" : (Var5 = "" ? "Empty" : "Non-empty"))
```

But really, pretty much always (at least if you design your program well) you'll be fine by just evaluating a boolean value from the variable, as shown in the other answer. This way you can easily just check the variable's *existence* with in an if-statement `if (var)`.

```
var1 := ""
var2 := "hello"
var3 := "0"
var4 := false
var5 := -1

MsgBox, % !!var1 "`n"
        . !!var2 "`n"
        . !!var3 "`n"
        . !!var4 "`n"
        . !!var5 "`n"
```

The only caveat is that there is no difference between `false` <sub><sup>(and `0` (`false` is a built in variable containing `0`))</sup></sub>, `""` and an actually non-existent variable.

---

AHKv2 implements its own built-in function for this:
https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/commands/IsSet.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I typically use to detect empty variables

Code:

```
;#Warn

^r::
if(!PrevActiveClass){
    MsgBox not set yet
}
else{
    WinActivate ahk_class %PrevActiveClass%
}
return

^e::WinGetClass, PrevActiveClass, A ; Sets the variable to be the active window for testing
```

In AHK, an empty variable is treated as a boolean `false`. As such, you can check it in an `if` statement to determine whether it contains anything. The one caveat with this method (though it does not apply to your use case) is that it does not work as intended if you on assigning the boolean `false` value to the var.

Comment: If you uncomment `#Warn`, it still throws though.